# C++98 Wrapper for std::map::at()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I can only use C++98 and have no access to the implentation of `std::map::at()` which was added with C++11.

My goal is to write a non member function `at()` function (using C++98) that behaves like `std::map::at()`.

Therefore I wrote the following non member function:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
V& at(std::map<K, V> map, K key)
{
  if (map.find(key) == map.end())
    throw std::out_of_range("key not found");
  return map.find(key)->second;
}
```

I can see at least one problem which is that my version behaves as if I had returned a copy (see below).

```
std::map<int,int> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(2,43));

// myMap.at(2)=44;            // modifies the reference
// assert(44==myMap.at(2));   // fine 

at(myMap,2)=44;               // does not modify the value inside the map, why?
assert(44==myMap.at(2));      // not fine
```

1. How can I address this problem?
2. Are there any other issues with my wrapper?

Comment: You should store the result of `find` in a variable in order not to traverse the map twice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what amounts to a typo.

Comment: @KubaOber I disagree.  The question is more about a lack of understanding of why passing a `map` by value does not modify the element than a simple typo.  The OP clearly does not understand why passing it by value fails to work as he expects.

Comment: Assuming your keys are all printable, you can enhance the error message too by stating what key was not found. May help you find the errors later should this error ever get thrown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue is that you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Your `at` takes the map by value:

```
V& at(std::map<K, V> map, K key)
```

so you're returning a reference to an item in a local object, which is very undefined.

You should use a reference:

```
V& at(std::map<K, V>& map, const K& key)
```

You probably want to add the const version, as well:

```
const V& at(const std::map<K, V>& map, const K& key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature to

```
V& at(std::map<K, V>& map, K key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You ave 2 issues in your method:

- You pass map instance as value so not only copying whole map but also returning reference to an element in that local copy and producing UB
- You do lookup twice, which is pretty expensive operation on map

So your code could be:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
V& at(std::map<K, V> &map, K key)
{
   std::map<K,V>::iterator f = map.find(key);
   if ( f == map.end())
     throw std::out_of_range("key not found");
   return f->second;
}
```